# Strange Function with duplicate name "DoBenchmark" cannot be defined as the function is defined only at one place

Tags: windows, matlab, mex

(With Matlab 2018b under latest windows10.) I have a folder `Folder` containing `DoStuff.m` whose code is :

```
%addpath('./SubFolder/SubSubFolder'); // SubSubFolder contains mex file defining myFunction used below
%close all;

function [res] = DoStuff(param) % Function has same name as the script defining it

    res = myFunction(param)

end
```

where `myFunction` is defined in a `mexw64` file contained in `'./SubFolder/SubSubFolder'`.

Naturally, as it is, executing the function DoStuff(param) inside Matlab's GUI (in the folder `Folder`) throws the following error :

```
'myFunction' is not found in the current folder or on the MATLAB path, but exists in ...
```

... in `'./SubFolder/SubSubFolder'`. Superb. I therefore remove the `%` in the first line of `DoStuff.m` and re-execute the function DoStuff(param) inside Matlab's GUI (in the folder `Folder`) and get the following error :

```
Function with duplicate name "DoStuff" cannot be defined.
```

Strange, as `DoStuff` is defined at only one place : insided the `DoStuff.m` script. (Confirmed by a `which -all DoStuff` in Matlab in `Folder`.)

*Remark.* In Matlab2018b one **can** defined a function named `toto` inside a script named `toto.m`, Matlab won't have any problem with it. So that my problem has nothing to do with the same naming. It has to do with adding the `addpath` line, but I don't know how. Confirmation of this feeling : replacing line `res = myFunction(param)` with `res = 1` and uncommenting the addpath leads to the naming error as well.

Comment: That remark is totally wrong and based on misunderstanding. Try saving [this code](https://pastebin.com/CHVa5uug) with the name DoStuff.m and run it. See what you get. You CANNOT define a function named `toto` inside a script named `toto`. If there is no executable line in a script before you define your function then it is a function file not a script file and hence it is totally fine

Comment: I would suggest, as I did in my answer to an earlier question of yours, to put the MEX-file in `Folder/private`. `private` is a special kind of directory that you do not need to add to the path. The functions in it are accessible only to the functions in `Folder`.

Comment: `addpath` affects MATLAB globally. You cannot change the path for one function only. Additionally it carries a large overhead, as MATLAB needs to index the directory added to the path. Your M-file that calls the MEX-file should not have this overhead if you want to call it repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the m-file must be different that that of the function if the function is inside a script file. i.e your m-filename cannot be `DoStuff.m` if `DoStuff` is not a function file. Either `DoStuff.m` should be a function file like this:

```
function [res] = DoStuff(param) % Note that there is no executable line before this
res = myFunction(param)
end
```

or you should rename either your function or your m-file.

Assuming you rename your m-file, you may use it like this:

```
addpath('./SubFolder/SubSubFolder'); %SubSubFolder contains mex file defining myFunction
close all;

res = DoStuff(param); %Calling the function

function [res] = DoStuff(param)
res = myFunction(param)
end
```

Comment: "The name of the m-file must be different that that of the function if the function is inside a script file. i.e your m-filename cannot be `DoStuff.m` if `DoStuff` is not a function file."  I don't understand this, I have tons of examples of analogue functions defined in scripts of the same name (but not calling mex functions nor having addpaths) that work perfectly. Typically, if I replace `res = myFunction(param)` with `res = 1` and leave the `addpath` line commented, Matlab won't complain.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr What do you mean an analogue function? There is no such term

Comment: By "analogue", I mean "ressembling". Look at my previous comment in details. And "The name of the m-file must be different that that of the function if the function is inside a script file." --> this is false. Try it in Matlab, you'll see you indeed can define a function named `toto` inside a script named `toto.m`, Matlab won't have any problem with it.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr The main part is "leave the addpath line commented" . That changes everything. Uncomment it and you'll see the same thing. You do not have any executable line in those files; otherwise you will definitely get that error.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr with emphasis on the word "executable". If you have an executable line before defining the function then your m-file is actually a script containing the function; not a function file. Note that lines with comments are not executable

Comment: Could please correct your answer to make clear what the solution is ? Because your "either" part is false. I repeat what my problem is : I call a function calling a function `toto` from a "function" script named `toto.m`, and that function `toto` calls a function `tata` of a mexfile placed `somewhere`. If I don't addpath to `somewhere` matlab naturally tells me that it cannot find `tata`. If I do add path to `somewhere`, it complains about same name for `toto`. Please see also the edit to my question, I just wrote it.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr The either part is not false. Before jumping to conclusions, please understand what is being told. Try saving [this code](https://pastebin.com/CHVa5uug) with the name DoStuff.m and run it. See what you get

Comment: So you are saying that it is because my script doesn't start with `function`, and that I should rather add the `addpath` inside Matlab's command line ?

Comment: @ujsgeyrr NO. `function` shouldn't necessarily be the first line but it should be the first EXECUTABLE line if you have it as a function file. If you're having a function inside a script file then the names must be different. When you comment out the addpath line, it becomes a function file. When those lines are not comments then it becomes a script file containing the function. There is a big difference